# Looking for a "Terms and Agreements" license dialog/screen for iOS app

Tags: ios, uikit

I need to place the conventional Terms and Agreements with agree/disagree acknowledgment in my iOS app. I had hoped that Apple would have a standard control for this, since it seems like a pretty common/standard thing. Or barring that, there would be a couple available on github.

If there is, I'm having a hard time locating them, because when you search, you just end up with everyone's own T&A for their own software.

Is it true that everyone just rolls their own? Or can anyone make a suggestion of a good library for this that I've just missed so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a control, **SFSafariViewController** would be an option. But **WKWebView** would be the best one.

One of the tools you can use in combination with the mentioned proposed controls is:
https://www.termsfeed.com/

Voila!

Answer (score 0):

It's important to know that a terms and agreements contract is **not** legally required to be on your app, but, a Privacy Policy **is** for an app or website. (https://www.rocketlawyer.com/document/online-privacy-policy.rl) is a really easy way to create one for your app.

You do not have to worry about adding an "agree" or "disagree" button, what is much easier is to put the following before people login:

"The privacy policy (or terms and conditions) will be in effect when you continue on the app after the login page." -- Then make sure you add a link to the Privacy Policy.

On your app page, import the following:

```
import UIKit
import Social
import SafariServices
```

and add this code to present the page as an SFSafariViewController

```
 if let requestUrl = URL(string: "https://www.privacyPolicyExample.com") {
            let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: "https://www.privacyPolicyExample.com")
            viewController?.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```